# Error al hacer restore de la base de datos en Odoo

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, odoo, openerp

Estoy usando Odoo en localhost a través de Docker para un trabajo en parejas. El problema que tengo es que mi compañero de trabajo me ha enviado una backup de su base de datos para que yo la importe en mi máquina y pueda seguir el trabajo que ha hecho él pero al hacer restore aparece el siguiente error: `Database restore error: "There is no item named 'dump.sql' in the archive"` Pero he revisado el fichero .zip y sí que está el fichero dump.sql por lo que no entiendo el error.
[image: Esta es la imagen del error]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes también los otros archivos **filestore** y **manifest.json** dentro del zip?

El archivo debe quedar asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí, está tal cual

Comment: Se me ocurre entonces que el nombre del archivo tenga alguna particularidad de espacio o carácter raro sino, el permiso. Si por A o B motivo es permiso, descomprime el ZIP, le pones todos los permisos o le sacas solo lectura (depende si estás windows o linux) y lo vuelves a comprimir. También te sugiero revisar el dump.sql si está completo hasta el final el backup.